# How do I search for a group in Facebook?

Tags: search, facebook

I am new to Facebook, and I can't find the way to search for groups I might be interested in.

The search input text only returns Applications, Pages and People.

Comment: You might also want to check out https://www.facebook.com/findgroups to see groups that your friends have joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are more of a url-typing type of guy, then -

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=<term>&type=groups
```

Replace `<term>` with a search term. :)

Comment: it's awesome,when i click it,the left menu show me the Groups,and next on,I can handle with groups at will

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for the group name in the search box, Then click on the "Group" tab in the left. All the groups matched within your search term would be showed. See attached.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22451404/Group%20Search.png

Comment: Your image is no longer available.